# Why doesn't .sln files use XML format in .NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

What was the particular reason behind that decision? It confuses me even more, since .csproj files has XML format.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `.sln` file format was introduced nearly 15 years ago by Visual InterDev 97.
XML was only defined in 1998.

Comment: @0A0D: I believe that back then, Visual Studio was a bundle (like Office), not an application.

Comment: Not arguing : http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41L6xyud0mL._SL500_AA300_.jpg

Comment: 0A0D: The point is that back then VS wasn't a single IDE for all products. VB had its own file formats, VC++ as well and apparently only InterDev used the `.sln` file format initially.

Comment: @0A0D: Yes, but it was a package, not an application.  (Just like there is no program called `Office`)