# Can project files like the ones with extension .csproj have other formats than XML?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

When we build a C# project in Visual Studio, a file with extension .csproj is created, which lists the contents of the project and configures how it should be built. It's said that a .csproj file has XML format, however, I've been reading the book "Programming C#" by Ian Griffiths which said the format of a project file is "usually" XML. So I'm asking if there is any other formats for project files? If yes what are the formats and where are they used?

Comment: No, there is no other format than the XML-based `.csproj` available

Comment: There was `project.json` during the .NET Core 1.x era, but that's no longer in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find good information in this document: [Understanding the project file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/understanding-the-project-file)
Microsoft Build Engine (MSBuild) project files are based on the MSBuild XML schema.

Answer (score 0):

Historically, the Visual Studio project files weren't XML files, and were gradually migrated to the now common XML MsBuild format. (This is discussed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/1730#issuecomment-671344494).) In particular, the VDPROJ project (old-style MSI installer project) is not an XML project at all, but this project type is now no longer supported in Visual Studio, and WIXPROJ (Wix Toolset project - a third-party project for the creation of MSI installer) is recommended instead. (The project type can also be supported using a Visual Studio extension.) The leftover of this era is the solution (SLN) file, which still hasn't been migrated to XML; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656016/why-doesnt-sln-files-use-xml-format-in-net).